# C#による正規表現で句読文字を判別するには

Tags: c#, .net, 正規表現

与えられた文字列から句読文字を探し出すプログラムを作成しています。

```
        String str = "while i < 10 {";
        String regexpat_test = "[\\p{P}]?";
        Regex rgx_test = new Regex(regexpat_test);
        MatchCollection matchCol_test = rgx_test.Matches(str);
        foreach (Match match in matchCol_test)
        {
            String strtest = match.Value;
        }
```

しかしこれにてmatchに入るのは空の文字列のみです。
\p{P}で句読文字に対応すると考えておりましたが、何か他に
設定するような事項があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 正規表現のタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` を付けているので句読文字以外の長さ0の文字列が混じっていないでしょうか？

`?` を抜いて実行すると、matchCol_test に `{` だけ格納されるかと思います。

Comment: その通りでしょう。元のコードでは、14文字に対して15個の結果が得られ、その全部が空の文字列(=長さ0の\p{P})ではなく、14番目(matchCol_test[13])に'{'が入りますね。

Comment: "{"が格納されるのを確認しました、ありがとうございます。
しかし、句読文字には"<"も含まれていると思っていましたので"<"の次に"{"が格納されるような動きになると思っていたのですが、"<"が格納されません。
なぜでしょうか？

Comment: "<"(U+003C; LESS-THAN SIGN)はMath_Symbolですので \p{Sm} にマッチします。